# I'm having a lot of trouble with the pageswap

Tags: jquery

```
function pageSwap(page) {
 $(".content").fadeOut("1000",function(){
  $(".content").load(page, function (){
   $(".content").fadeIn("5000");    
  });
 });
}
```

This is included into my page from pageswap.js,
then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
   $(".content").pageSwap("main.html");
 });
</script>
```

I do have main.html, the script included, function called, but it won't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared a global function but haven't extended jQuery with this function. So you simply need to call `pageSwap()` like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        pageSwap("main.html");
    });
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE**: You can extend JQuery with `pageSwap` method using the following code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        pageSwap: function(page) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var obj = $(this);
                obj.fadeOut("1000", function() {
                    obj.load(page, function() {
                        obj.fadeIn("5000");
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

However, there is another alternative approach described in [@Esailija's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833146/1249581).

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this for your code to work:

```
$.fn.pageSwap = function(page) {
    this.fadeOut("1000", $.proxy( function(){
        this.load(page, $.proxy( function (){
            this.fadeIn("5000");    
        }, this ));
    }, this ));
};
```